# スペースをJavaの「SimpleDateFormat」の「parse」について

Tags: java

現在、文字列→日付への変換のために、
以下のようなコードを記述しています。

```
String pattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat =new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = sdFormat.parse("Wed May 29 2019");
```

しかしエラーが発生しています(下記)。
空白が原因のようなのですが、具体的な回避策がわかりません。

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 29 2019"
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

英語の曜日（Wed）と月（May）が含まれているので、英語のロケール（`Locale.US`とか`Locale.ENGLISH`とか）を使用しなければならないんじゃないですかね。

```
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat =new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
```

Comment: Kohei TAMURA さん
ありがとうございます!できました!
Localeを指定しなければUSになるのかと思っていたのですが、違うのですね

Comment: @seino [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)に、「これは、`SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT))`の呼び出しと同等です。」と書いてあります。なので、未指定だとおそらく、`ja_JP`になります。解決したら、クローズしておいて下さい。